# Taking a long time to execute a saltstack command using python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, salt-stack

I was trying to execute this saltstack command 
`cmd = "/usr/local/bin/salt -L 'target' cp.get_dir salt://allapps/V001 /u02/tomcat-8.0.24/8080/webapps/" 
output = os.popen(cmd).readlines()` using python.
I have started 8 threads in parallel to run this command, but each thread costs about 5 min to finish.
But I run this command in terminal or python console standalone, it just takes me about 2-3 secs to complete.
First I thought it was because of readlines() consuming lots of memory, but it still costs 5 min more to finish when I removed readlines() just to run the shell command with os.popen(). 
I have no idea why it takes so much time to run this command, any solutions to this? Thx guys

I have found that it consumes around 5 sec to execute `output = os.popen("/usr/local/bin/salt -L 'target' cp.get_dir salt://allapps/V001 /u02/tomcat-8.0.24/8080/webapps/")` other than `output = os.popen(cmd)`.
The variable `cmd` is exactly the same with `"/usr/local/bin/salt -L 'target' cp.get_dir salt://allapps/V001 /u02/tomcat-8.0.24/8080/webapps/"`.
Why there is so much difference?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that command is taking so long. Have you considered using Salt's python api?  https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/clients/index.html#python-api

Comment: I have tried Salt's python api, but it's still hanging about 5 mins to run this command.