# Saltstack minions always lost connections in python scripts

Tags: python, salt-stack

I started 9 threads in parallel to publish a .war file to 9 instances of tomcat on 9 minions using cp.get_file function, and the codes are like this below:

```
salt -L <target> cp.get_file salt://file /tomcat/webapps/file
```

During the running process of this script, it will be hanging for about 5 mins to run the command [(in this post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405520/taking-a-long-time-to-execute-a-saltstack-command-using-python). After completion, I found that most of the results are like `Minion did not return. [No response]`. Actually these minions are all connected when I try `test.ping` in CLI. I have no idea why this happened, I have spent days solving this problem.

Comment: While with limited information - it is very hard to say. It could be that the operation is timing out because you are transferring a large file? Or it could be your network setup that is not optimal. If you can add more details and also run the salt with "-l debug" as a additional argument - we will know better. There is also an open bug related to this issue: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/12246

Comment: `cp.get_file` is not designed to transfer big files, meanwhile you can always see if job is still running with `salt-run jobs.active`